# Joi.validate îs not a function

Tags: javascript, function, express, joi

I am trying to build a validation function using job

```
async function validateUser(user) {
  const schema = Joi.object({
      password: Joi.string().pattern((new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$'))),
      repeat_password: Joi.any().equal(Joi.ref('password')).required().messages({ 'any.only': '{{#label}} does not match' }),
      email: Joi.string().email({ minDomainSegments: 2, tlds: { allow: ['com', 'dk']}})
    });
    try {
        const value = await schema.validateAsync((user));
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

however the repeat_password does not work properly,

```
firstname: 'Mette ',
    lastname: 'Nielsen',
    age: "'35'",
    gender: 'female',
    about: 'I like to go and watch movies',
    email: 'mettenielsen@23245.gaga',
    password: 'metteNielsen123',
    repeat_password: 'mette',
    likes: 'Shopping, going to the mall, cities',
    dislikes: 'rap musik, events, poor people'
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.3.0#example for working example.

Comment: it works, but I get a new problem now, my repeat_password is not doing it properly

Comment: What the problem? you get "repeat_password" does not match, that's the expected behavior

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
async function validateUser(user) {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        password: Joi.string().pattern((new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$'))),
        repeat_password: Joi.any().equal(Joi.ref('password')).required().messages({ 
        'any.only': '{{#label}} does not match' }),
        email: Joi.string().email({ minDomainSegments: 2, tlds: { allow: 
        ['com','dk']}})
     });
     try {
         const value = await schema.validateAsync((user));
     } catch (err) {
         console.log(err)
     }
 }
```

Please avoid to validate the schema directly, you can try something like

```
async function validateUser(user) {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        password: Joi.string().pattern((new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$'))),
        repeat_password: Joi.any().equal(Joi.ref('password')).required().messages({ 
        'any.only': '{{#label}} does not match' }),
        email: Joi.string().email({ minDomainSegments: 2, tlds: { allow: 
        ['com','dk']}})
     });
     const {error, value} = schema.validate(user)
     // Then if the data is correct, the error will be undefined, so you can check like: 
     if (!error) {
     // Everything is okay 
     } else {
         // You can put a message here 
     }
 }
```